# mysql COUNT(*) always returns 8

Tags: php, mysql

The title says it all.  I have the below code:

```
public function getRows($table) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."`");
    if (! $result) {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error().".  Query was:\n\n".$query."\n\nError number: ".mysql_errno() . ".Table = ".$table);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Seems like it should be the easiest function ever, but the result always returns 8.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: There are 8 records in your table?

Comment: There're endless use examples in the manual. Why are you trying to guess how mysql_...() functions work?

Comment: @Tdelang Nice one :-)

Comment: aggregate functions are always used with GROUP BY clause..

Comment: @BhavikShah - they're not and it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @strauberry Imposter! :-)

Comment: @N.B. : Yes they are aggregate functions are also called GROUP BY functions because they are used with GROUP  BY clause always in production level codes. I know it has nothing to do with the problem, that is why it is posted as comment and not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a `mysql_query()` function result, which is NOT the results of your SQL query.

You have to do something like `mysql_fetch_assoc()` with the `mysql_*` old PHP functions.

PS: You should use PDO now, `mysql_*` are deprecated, it's just a tip ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get number of records in your result

```
public function getRows($table) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `".$table."`");
    if (! $result) {
        // throw exception
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    return $row['count'];
}
```

Also. as previous responder pointed out, you need to stop using `mysql_*` funcitons and start using either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. [PHP Docs for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns a resource: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Returning that value won't give you the result of the query. You need mysql_fetch_array().

A working example:

```
public function getRows($table) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."`");
    if (! $result) {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error().".  Query was:\n\n".$query."\n\nError number: ".mysql_errno() . ".Table = ".$table);
    }
    if($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        return $row[0];
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get result using `mysql_fetch_array()` `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_object()`

```
public function getRows($table) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `".$table."`");
    if (! $result) {
        // throw exception
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    return $row['count'];
}
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch your query , not return the mysql_query.

try this

```
  public function getRows($table) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM `".$table."`");
if (! $result) {
    throw new Exception(mysql_error().".  Query was:\n\n".$query."\n\nError number: ".mysql_errno() . ".Table = ".$table);
}
$row =mysql_fetch_array($result) ;
return $row['counts'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using mysql_num_rows as it does not need to fetch any data and is more efficient

```
public function getRows($table) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."`");
    if (! $result) {
        // throw exception
    }
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

    return $rows;
}
```